# Xaml textblock alignment in a listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8, listbox

I am developing an windows phone app and I want to show six textblock in a listbox but The problem is all 6 values are sticked to each other. I want to give some spaces in between so that they look better when shown. Like for example what they look like currently is

`Date|time|floor|zone|latitude|longtitude` and I would like them to look like

`Date | Time | floor | zone | latitude | longtitude`

I hope I am able to explain it clearly 
below is my xaml code

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
x:Class="SmartParking.History"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls"   
mc:Ignorable="d"
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
    <shell:ApplicationBar>
        <shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
            <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem IsEnabled="True" Text="Delete all" Click="DeleteAll_Click"/>
        </shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Assets7/AppBar/delete.png" IsEnabled="True" Text="Delete" Click="Delete_Click" />
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Assets8/AppBar/feature.search.png" IsEnabled="True" Text="Search"/>
    </shell:ApplicationBar>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>

<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
        <TextBlock Text="Smart Parking" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="History" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <ListBox x:Name="ListData" SelectionChanged="ListData_SelectionChanged">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock x:Name=  "DateTxt"  Text="{Binding Date}"   TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                        <TextBlock x:Name=  "TimeTxt"  Text="{Binding Time}"  TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                        <TextBlock x:Name=  "ZoneTxt"  Text="{Binding Zone}"  TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                        <TextBlock x:Name=  "FloorTxt" Text="{Binding Floor}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                        <TextBlock x:Name=  "LatTxt"   Text="{Binding latitude}" TextWrapping="Wrap"  />
                        <TextBlock x:Name=  "LongTxt"  Text="{Binding longtitude}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Well there are different ways to do it, you can simply add margins to your textblocks or replacing the `Stackpanel` in the datatemplate by a `Grid` with `ColumnDefinitions` then setting a `Grid.Column` for each `TextBlock` in the end it's all up to you :)

Comment: @aymeric do you have any samples or could you describe it in some detail

Comment: Regarding the `Margin` you can set to your textblock as `<TextBlock x:Name="TimeTxt" Text="{Binding Time}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="3,0,3,0/>` which will give 3px margin on the left and right of your `TextBlock`

Answer (score 0):

You can add margins to the textboxes as follows-

```
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock x:Name=  "DateTxt"  Text="{Binding Date}"   TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="10,0,10,0" />
                    <TextBlock x:Name=  "TimeTxt"  Text="{Binding Time}"  TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="10,0,10,0"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name=  "ZoneTxt"  Text="{Binding Zone}"  TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="10,0,10,0"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name=  "FloorTxt" Text="{Binding Floor}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="10,0,10,0"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name=  "LatTxt"   Text="{Binding latitude}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="10,0,10,0" />
                    <TextBlock x:Name=  "LongTxt"  Text="{Binding longtitude}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="10,0,10,0"/>
                </StackPanel>
```

Here, margin can be defined in the following ways-

```
Margin="<Left>, <Top>, <Right>, <Bottom>"
```

eg. - Margin="5,10,15,20"

`Margin="<Horizontal>, <Vertical>"` - here horizontal means margin on left & right while Vertical means margin on top & bottom
eg. - Margin="5,10"

`Margin="<All Sides>"` - same margin will be applied on all sides
eg. - Margin="10"